# Django: GET jquery 404 error

Tags: jquery, python, django

My django is getting a 404 error when trying to get the `jquery-2.2.4.js` file. However, it is getting the `css/boardcss.css` file just fine, even though they are both in the same top-level /static/ folder, after doing collectstatic. Any help?

Here is the jquery 404 error when I run my site:

```
Django version 1.9.6, using settings 'tictactoe.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[06/Jun/2016 23:04:21] "GET /board/ HTTP/1.1" 200 361
[06/Jun/2016 23:04:21] "GET /static/jquery-2.2.4.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1658
[06/Jun/2016 23:04:21] "GET /static/css/boardcss.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

My HTML file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-2.2.4.js' %}">
</script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/boardcss.css' %}">
</head>
<body class="body" style="background-color:#545454">
    <div class='container-fluid'>
               {% block content %}
               {% endblock %}   
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

From my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "board", "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

My directory tree:

[image: adsf]

Comment: dont you have a sub directory for .js files ? js/jquery-2.2.4.js ?

Comment: @glls No, is it required?

Comment: not required, but a best practice

Comment: can you add a screenshot  of your directory tree? or write it out, and are you sure you are not using the .min version

Comment: @glls I added the directory tree. I am not using the .min version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so you have 2 static folders. I believe that is your problem. note when you go up one level and then look for static, in one of them you have a jquery file and the other you don't.

you might need to configure:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS

```
[
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

> The list of finder backends that know how to find static files in
>   various locations.

Comment: but my STATIC_ROOT is set as (BASE_DIR, "static"), so shouldn't it only look in the top level static folder?

Comment: what html is the script failing in? base.html? from the board templates?

Comment: it was base.html from /board/templates/board/

Comment: can you add the jquery file to your other static? if it doesn't work either, than I am wrong and I will delete this post =/

Comment: Ok it worked now after putting it my other static. But I'm still concerned why it wasn't looking at the top-level static. I was told to use collectstatic and put all my static files there...

Comment: can you show me how you configured STATICFILES_FINDERS ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113974/discussion-between-glls-and-theeyeshaveit).

Comment: When I used staticfiles_finders (the default settings), I am still getting the same issue. It seems it looks for files within subdirectory of an app, which is not my case.

Comment: O.o. let me look further and modify my answer